# Magento - Using same template on mutiple blocks causing error

Tags: list, magento, tabs, categories, product

I have 3 jQuery tabs and want to fill each tab with products from different categories. The tabs are displayed on a category page. In the category page "custom layout update" I have this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="38" limit="6" name="tabs_new" template="catalog/product/tab_list.phtml" />
<block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="39" limit="6" name="tabs_topsellers" template="catalog/product/tab_list.phtml" />
<block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="40" limit="6" name="tabs_sale" template="catalog/product/tab_list.phtml" />
```

tab_list.phtml is just a copy of list.phtml with the toolbars stripped out and some markup changes.

In my category view.phtml file I have the following:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tabs_topsellers') ?>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tabs_new') ?>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tabs_sale') ?>
</div>
```

But when I go to the page, I get this error:

```
Mage registry key "isList" already exists
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

For fast fix you can use `Mage::unregister('isList');` before echo each block

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly as a quick fix but it would be better to find a different solution for what I'm trying to achieve. This is helpful though.

Comment: A better solution would be not writing anything in the registry from inside the template because this violates the separation of view and logic. Unfortunately Magento itself is not coded very clean regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions :

- before registering a value, check if it exists already with :

  if (!Mage::registry('isList')) {
      Mage::register('isList');
  }
- use the third parameter "`$graceful`" of the `Mage::register()` function in order to ignore the registering of an existing variable (it doesn't throw an exception and do just nothing)

Comment: I don't actually have `Mage::register('isList');` anywhere in my own code. The only thing I've done is replicate and rename a template file.

Comment: and in this duplicated file (or it's linked block), you have a Mage::register I sassume ?

Answer (score 0):

Awesome I had a similar issue with Ultimo theme.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Mage registry key "isList" already exists' in /home/devlovethe/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
```

I was trying to use  product_list_featured for multiple categories.

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="97" product_count="12" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 4], [960, 5], [1280, 6]" pagination="1" centered="1" hide_button="1" block_name="Our Featured Products"}}
```

At the end of list_featured_slider.phtml I added

```
<?php Mage::unregister('isList'); ?>
```